# Setting AuthenticatedSubject for all ressources

Tags: weblogic, credentials, java-security

I have a web app running on weblogic 10.3.

Is it possible to make sure, that **AuthenticatedSubject** is always in place for all resources? Ideally by setting some default authentication for all apps, so that I dont have to modify every application's security settings.

Can I enforce, that the user has to authenticate himself once and to keep him as a principal for each request?

I tried to set up an authentication-provider in my applications realm, but it is not triggered.
I think I have to say weblogic, that all resources have to be protected in my realm.
How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is explained in this document : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/pdf/security.pdf

You have to configure your web-app with a secutiry contraint to protect your application and force users to be authenticated

Comment: And is there a general solution, on weblogic level?
Is it possible to say, that ALL resources are protected, without modifiying every web.xml ? so that if no authenticated user is inside the context - that the user is asked to authenticate himself.

Comment: I think you can achieve this using roles and policies : 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/secwlres/index.html

Comment: Thats 100% right, thnx. This can be achieved so configure a root level policy via the Administrator console. Ataching a policy which requers the User to be in group "MY_GROUP" to the URL resource was the solution. After that WLS triggered a user/password. Details about policies are described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/security/CreateRootLevelPolicies.html